# returning a value to a c# program through python script

Tags: c#, python

I have a C# program which executes a python scrip

How can I retrieve the python returning value in my C# program ?

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the exit code, which is just an integer value, or a more elaborate value, like a string?

Comment: an integer, which indicates if the python script ran successfuly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your using System.Diagnostics.Process to launch your python script, then you can get the return code after process exit

using

```
process.ExitCode
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you should use ScriptScope object which you create from the ScriptEngine object using CreateScope method

```
ScriptEngine engine = ScriptRuntime.Create().GetEngine("py");
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
```

Then you can share variables between the C# program and the python script by doing this

```
scope.SetVariable("x", x);
```

Comment: I assume this is only for IronPython? Still interesting though.

Comment: Yes this is for both IronPython & IronRuby, I thought you meant Iron Python in the first place :)